POSIX definition of a text file seems to accept a file consisting of a single incomplete line as a text file - is this intentional?
POSIX defines a text file as "a file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines". However, according to POSIX definition of a line, there are two possible "kinds" of text files with zero lines:

an empty file
a non-empty file consisting solely of a single incomplete line (a line with at least one character and no \n).

Is the second case above really considered a text file? Intuitively it's not, as it seems to be nothing more but an edge case. Still, such a file certainly has no lines (as POSIX defines them) because it does not contain a newline character, so it seems to adhere to the current POSIX definition of a text file. The only issue open to interpretation here may be whether such files can be considered "organized into lines", but personally I see no reason against it - nothing in the POSIX definition forces me to treat them otherwise than empty files which, despite being empty (and thus trivially having zero lines), are considered "organized in lines". Perhaps I'm splitting hairs here, but I think the definition, as it currently stands, requires a slight augmentation in order to exclude this case (unless I'm wrong and such files are indeed supposed to match the POSIX definition of a text file).
In this thread:
What conditions must be met for a file to be a text file as defined by POSIX?
the OP had similar doubts. In one of replies to his questions someone claimed that "a text file shall not have incomplete lines". While this extra statement would indeed exclude the disputed case, such a restriction does not explicitly appear in the POSIX definition of a text file.

It's not clear what your question here is. You have to question marks in your post, one in the title "is it intentional?", which would be a historical question, and since "intention" is a quest for opinion, probably not the greatest for a platform that actively discourages asking for opinions. The second question is "is a file with no newline a text file" and the answer to that has already been given in the previous question: no it isn't. Whether you or I like that or not. (I'm fine with that definition.)

@MarcusMüller Firstly, I think my question was pretty comprehensible, but let me rephrase it: "Why is an empty file generally considered a text file while a non-empty file without newline characters is not if, according to POSIX, either both should be text files, or none of them, and if that signifies a flaw in definition?" Secondly, it's not a matter of preference, but rather a matter of adherence of specific files to a specific definition. Thirdly: you just proved to have read the older thread superficially if you claim anyone there said that ANY file with no newline is not a text file.

@Peter thanks for the clarification. But this leaves the original problem: "it's not a matter of preferences, but rather a matter of adherence to specifications": so, what's the question here? Empty file is a text file, file with text but no line break is not; you basically cite the relevant specification that says exactly that. Case closed!

So, then the remaining question is "if that signifies a flaw in the definition": Unless you can point out to something that makes the definition conflict with another definition, that's not a flaw, I'd say. What indication do you have for it being a flaw?

@MarcusMüller the relevant specification is very confusing and unclear. It would have been better for it to expolicitly state that a file with data but whose data are not organized into lines (i.e. don't end with \n) is not a file. Yes, that can be inferred from the specs, but only if you squint a bit and spend a long time trying to parse it. I can completely understand (and share) Peter's confusion.

@MarcusMüller "A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines" - exactly what in this definition implies a distinction between an empty file and a non-empty file without '\n' characters? How do you deduce from it that the former is the text file and the latter is not? Both files, according to POSIX definition of a line, have zero lines.

@Peter the literal words make that distinction. It's not implied, it's explicit: a text file is a sequence of lines (and that sequence can be empty). Therefore, an empty file is a text file. There's no corner-casing here, nor anything unspecific. The specification of "text file" literally starts with "a file that contains … in zero or more lines". So zero lines is a valid text file.

If you think foo is a valid text file since it contains zero lines, why not also assume that foo\nbar is a valid text file since it contains more than zero lines?

I think it's relatively obvious here that the intent is that a text file consists of zero or more lines, and nothing else. It's just that the last part is left implicit.

@MarcusMüller Ok, here we agree. But a non-empty file without any '\n' character in it has zero lines as well (it does have one "invalid line", but zero "lines" as far as POSIX definition of a line is concerned). What makes you not consider it a text file, then?

In any case, does it reeeally matter what the definition is supposed to be? Would it not be enough to consider the practical effects of having or not having that last newline? E.g. the fact that wc -l is defined to count newline characters, or that cat one two > both works pretty badly of one doesn't end in a newline... Regardless of any strict interpretation, there are a lot of (implementations of) standard utilities which in practice just silently add the newline if missing, so it's not that anyone is out to get you on purpose if you break the rules...

@ilkkachu Careful, you went one step too far! "foo\nbar" is NOT a valid text file, as it contains one "line" and one "incomplete line", NOT two lines (POSIX is very specific, albeit sometimes counterintuitive about what a "line" is). It's a mix-up of a line and trailing part which is not considered a line, hence your example does not constitute a valid text file.

@Peter, why not? It contains one line, so obviously "zero or more lines". Why would you accept the additional non-line in one case (zero complete lines) but not in the other (more than zero complete lines)? I don't see the definition make a difference between the cases of zero and more than zero. (And if the step I'm taking too far is the step of taking your argument into its logical conclusion, then, well, if you don't like that...)

as for "I think the definition, as it currently stands, requires a slight augmentation", I think the forum for discussing the wording and interpretation of the standard is the Austin Group mailing list and bug tracker, not unix.SE, though someone else will need to verify the details for you.

@ilkkachu Because "foo\nbar" would violate the condition that "a text file needs to have its data organized into lines". While the condition is underspecified (especially in the "zero-lines" case, hence my thread), I think we can agree that it has a well-defined meaning for any file containing at least one line - in this common case it means that every character in the file is contained within some line, empty lines are allowed as well, but no content is allowed after the last line.

@Peter, so how does foo have its data organized into lines, then? It obviously has characters that outside any lines, i.e. not organized into lines. Or, to look it the other way around, taking the definition terdon quoted below: "A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines.", I could note that foo\nbar definitely contains characters organized into lines, namely the characters foo\n.

At the risk of being a bit blunt, all this frankly reads to me that you've converged on one particular interpretation, and you've decided your interpretation is the only true one, regardless of how anyone else says they could interpret the text in a different way. (Note how you wrote the question saying "according the definition, there are two possible kinds", not e.g. "according to how I read it, ...", or  "it appears that...". That... doesn't really leave room for any arguments on the contrary, since you've already stated it is so.)

The sad thing with human languages is that they're often not at all unambiguous, and we just need to live with that, perhaps by way of talking things through with other people when ambiguity arises...

gonna contradict @ilkkachu there. The wording of the standard is clear about what a text file, and what a line is, and that an empty file explicitly is a text file. There's really no reason to appease any misinterpretation of that. (Peter to answer your question: literally the rest of the sentence, "characters organized into…" says that if a character is not part of a string of characters ended by \n, it can't be a text file). I'll be eqally blunt as ilkkachu there: this is all pretty straightforward, and you electing to have a problem with it is a bit of a "Peter" thing :) and doesn't…

… affect validity or correctness of a definition (only self-contradiction can invalidate a set of definitions).

@MarcusMüller, oh, I'm not saying that an empty file would not be a text file. Of course it is, it just has zero lines (but nothing else). What I tried to do above was to zero in on what their distinction between foo and foo\nbar was, since I don't see an interpretation that could make it work... But I am ready to accept that someone might have doubts about English definitions, this or others. It's just that when that happens, people should perhaps accept the unavoidable... fuzziness of human languages, and the ever-so-remote possibility that they might themselves be wrong...

@ilkkachu While I admit yours and terdon's interpretation is superior and I take it as the "intuitively right one", there is at least one plausible assumption leading to my (somewhat unorthodox) interpretation. I'll describe it in the next comment with no intention to prove anything to anyone, but just to answer some of the questions you asked me a few hours ago. Contrary to what some people here (especially you and Marcus Müller) may think I'm not trolling and I have not decided that my interpretation is the only true one.

@ilkkachu Assumption: "files whose characters are NOT organized into lines" are files containing at least one line, followed by an incomplete line (informally, files with mixed "line/non-line content"). Hence, all files not adhering to that definition (informally, those with "uniform line content", or "uniform non-line content", or empty) are "organized into lines". By this definition, all files with zero lines (both empty and non-empty) fall into the category of "files organized by lines" and, hence, match the definition of a text file.

@Peter, I never said you were trolling. I did note that you seemed obstinate, and I stand by what I said about the definitive tone of your statements and how useful it is. People can be obstinate while not trolling, trust me, I know from some quite personal experience. Though I do note, that the title of the Q here does say "seems to", I just don't see that in the post and even less in your comments.

Regardless, I still can't see how "files whose characters are NOT organized into lines" would require having at least one line? After all, if there are zero (complete) lines, then none of the content in the file is organized into lines. I can see some logic in reading the definition so that extra content apart from the lines is acceptable (though then pretty much anything would go, so it's not very useful a definition any more), but I can't see how it can be read so that the rules would be different for the cases of "zero lines" and "more than zero lines". Anyway, good night.

@ilkkachu Thank you for your patience. To sum up, the culprit of my rant was that I somehow failed to grasp the term "file with content organized into zero lines" and what it should actually mean. Then, I somehow assumed that either all files without at least one complete line should count as such (sort of an "else" or a "catch-all" case), or none of them should. Your definition: "a file with content organized into lines is a file which consists of zero or more lines, and nothing else" sums it up perfectly. I apologize to you and everyone else who think this discussion was a waste of time.

The full definition of a text file is:

A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. The lines do not contain NUL characters and none can exceed {LINE_MAX} bytes in length, including the <newline> character. Although POSIX.1-2017 does not distinguish between text files and binary files (see the ISO C standard), many utilities only produce predictable or meaningful output when operating on text files. The standard utilities that have such restrictions always specify "text files" in their STDIN or INPUT FILES sections.

This is admittedly a particularly confusing choice of words in the spec. The way I have understood it, after the discussion in the Q&A you linked to, is that the part of the specs you quote should be read as "a file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines". I.e. that a file is a text file only if its contents are organized into lines.
Next, POSIX defines "lines" as:

A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character.

And empty lines as:

A line consisting of only a <newline>; see also Blank Line.

So, we know that:

A text file needs to have its data organized into lines.
A text file is allowed to have 0 lines.
A line must end with a \n.

Combining these three points, this means that:

An empty file is a text file because it has its data organized into zero lines.
A non-empty file whose last character is not a newline is not a text file. This is because its data are not organized into lines.

I found the way Ilmari expressed it to me in a comment helpful, so I include it here:

[...] a POSIX text file is any file whose contents matches[sic] the regexp (.{0,M}\n)* (implicitly anchored and both ends), where \n matches a newline and . matches any character that is not a newline, and M is a placeholder for the numeric value LINE_MAX-1. In particular, this implies that an empty file is a valid text file consisting of zero lines, but that any non-empty text file must end in a newline (since otherwise it would contain an incomplete line, and an incomplete line is not a line).


But by applying this logic, both an empty file and a non-empty file without '\n' characters are "organized into zero lines", because both of them have zero "POSIX lines". Weird and artificial as it looks, if we consider a file with zero lines to "have data organized into lines", both equally apply. Or perhaps we need a more strict definition of a "file with data organized into lines" to make the proper distinction. Or, best of all, just add the statement "A text file shall not have incomplete lines." at the end of the POSIX definition which resolves the ambiguity.

You're quoting and linking to the previous version of the standard but that hasn't changed in the new version.

The (.{0,M}\n) vs "and M is a placeholder for the numeric value LINE_MAX-1" is inaccurate because the LINE_MAX limit is on a number of bytes, not characters while . matches a character, not byte. For instance, in a UTF-8 locale, a line could go over the limit if it has as few as LINE_MAX/4 characters because characters in UTF-8 can be encoded on up to 4 bytes.

@Peter yeah, I know, but I think the idea there is that a text file can only have lines, so non-\n characters without a \n at the end are not a line, therefore this file has non-lines and therefore is not a text file.

Thanks for the edit, @StéphaneChazelas. And yes, I am quoting the older specs because I started from the other answer, but as you confirm they're unchanged, I guess that's OK. As for the LINE_MAX, I'm sure you're right. The part that helped me understand was the regex bit, specifically that everything in the file had to match (.{0,M}\n)* which won't be the case if there are any non-\n characters that aren't terminated by a \n one.

I'm not sure "a file is a text file only if its contents are organized into lines" really helps, since it still doesn't say that there must not be anything in addition to those lines. But I'm not a native English speaker, so perhaps there's some connotation I'm missing. In any case, since this is pretty much of a hairsplitting discussion (IMO), I would just explicitly underline it with "and nothing else", or "all of its contents/characters organized into lines", or whatever.

@ilkkachu The definition seems intuitive enough to me for a common case of files with at least one line, and I assume it means "a file is a sequence of (possibly empty) lines and nothing more", so no content after the last line is allowed.

A "file" is a string of 8-bit bytes."Lines" are a secondary property. "Lines", deliimited by the characters in $IFS, are a convenient concept. Some editors (emacs) will warn-but-allow if I don't have a Newline at the end of a file. Also consider the process reading your STDOUT . Wouldn't it want to see your program's last gasp?

@waltinator this has nothing to do with the shell, so $IFS isn't relevant. It is about the POSIX definition of a text file.

Putting aside the NUL-byte, the last requirement would be LINE_MAX; is that the value returned by getconf LINE_MAX?

Here's another way to look at this:

A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines.

Your example file contains zero lines and a non-line.
The standard could be more clear by stating something like

A file that contains characters exclusively organized into zero or more lines.

or

A file that exclusively contains characters organized into zero or more lines.

Or something to that effect, but I think it is pretty clear as it stands now. There is no indication that the standard intends to allow a text file to contain non-lines or characters which aren't organized into lines.
